# Showing that $f$ is isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $_{F}V$ and $_{F}W$ be vector spaces, and let $f\in\hom(V, W)$ such that, for every  $g\in\hom(W, V)$, if $g$ is not the constant function $0_{V}$, then $f\circ g \circ f$ is not the constant function $0_{W}$. Show that $f$ is an isomorphism.

I really don't know where to start. I thought on taking $\ker(f)$ which is contained in $\ker(f\circ g\circ f)$ or look for a linear function $g$ not zero which helps me in some way but ideas don't come to my mind.

Comment: This is false if $W=\{0\}$ and $V\ne\{0\}:$ $f$ won't be an isomorphism, whereas "$g\ne0\Rightarrow fgf\ne0$" will be vacuously true, i.e. there is no non-zero $g\in\hom(W, V).$

Comment: Same problem if $V=\{0\}$ and $W\ne\{0\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints that might help.

Looking at $\ker(f)$ is a good start if you want to show that $f$ is injective.  Suppose that $f$ is not injective, so $\ker(f) \neq \{0_V\}$.  Can you see how to construct a $g \in \operatorname{hom}(W, V)$ such that $\operatorname{im}(g) \subseteq \ker(f)$ and $g$ is not identically zero?  If you can do that, do you see how it gives you a contradiction from the assumption that if $g$ is not identically zero then neither is $f \circ g \circ f$?

If you can get that part to work then showing that $f$ is surjective is somewhat similar - assume $\operatorname{im}(f) \neq W$ and use that to build a $g$ that contradicts the assumption of the problem.

Comment: Oh! I have it. Given that $\ker(f)\neq\{0_{V}\}$ then exists $v_{0}\in \ker(f)$ not zero so I can define $g(w)=v_{0}$ for $w\neq 0_{W}$ and $g(0_{W})=0_{V}$ and I finish

Comment: No, wait. That is not linear

Comment: Better I take $v_{0}$ only for one $w_{0}$ not zero and define $g$ equal zero for all $w$ different from $w_{0}$

Comment: That won't be linear either... probably better to think about a basis for $W$.

Comment: Right. I was about to say that xd. Thank you